# R: how to keep legitimate NAs in a merged zoo object

Tags: r, merge, zoo

I have multiple time-series objects with regular interval of five minutes, but they can have different start and end times. They can also log at different times, not necessarily at minutes 5,10,15, etc.

I want to merge those objects, but I want to keep the legitimate NAs intact. For example, one object start logging at a later time, then the NAs at the beginning are legitimate NAs. The same if one object stops logging earlier, then the NAs at the end are legitimate.

But there is not option to keep both NAs intact with na.locf.

Here is an example of my problem:

```
lines1="Index,x1
2014-01-01 00:00:00,73.06
2014-01-01 00:05:00,73.11
2014-01-01 00:10:00,73.16
2014-01-01 00:15:00,73.22"

lines2="Index,x2
2014-01-01 00:11:00,71.11
2014-01-01 00:16:00,70.12
2014-01-01 00:21:00,70.16
2014-01-01 00:26:00,70.19
2014-01-01 00:31:00,69.16"

lines3="Index,x3
2014-01-01 00:23:00,0
2014-01-01 00:28:00,1
2014-01-01 00:33:00,1
2014-01-01 00:38:00,0
2014-01-01 00:43:00,0"

df1=read.table(text = lines1, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
df2=read.table(text = lines2, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
df3=read.table(text = lines3, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

z1 = zoo(df1$x1, as.POSIXct(df1$Index))
z2 = zoo(df2$x2, as.POSIXct(df2$Index))
z3 = zoo(df3$x3, as.POSIXct(df3$Index))

z = merge(z1,z2,z3)
z

z.na.locf = na.locf(z)
z.na.locf

timesteps = seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 00:00:00"), 
                as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 01:00:00"),
                by = "5 min")

z.timesteps = na.locf(z, xout=timesteps)
z.timesteps
```

The merged object is this:

```
> z
                       z1    z2 z3
2014-01-01 00:00:00 73.06    NA NA
2014-01-01 00:05:00 73.11    NA NA
2014-01-01 00:10:00 73.16    NA NA
2014-01-01 00:11:00    NA 71.11 NA
2014-01-01 00:15:00 73.22    NA NA
2014-01-01 00:16:00    NA 70.12 NA
2014-01-01 00:21:00    NA 70.16 NA
2014-01-01 00:23:00    NA    NA  0
2014-01-01 00:26:00    NA 70.19 NA
2014-01-01 00:28:00    NA    NA  1
2014-01-01 00:31:00    NA 69.16 NA
2014-01-01 00:33:00    NA    NA  1
2014-01-01 00:38:00    NA    NA  0
2014-01-01 00:43:00    NA    NA  0
```

Note that the NAs in the beginning of z1 is legitimate, also in the end of z3, and in the beginning and end of z2. The NAs that need to be replaced are the ones in the middle of data. The problem is if I tried to fill in the missing values in the middle of the data, the legitimate NAs are gone too:

```
> z.na.locf
                       z1    z2 z3
2014-01-01 00:00:00 73.06    NA NA
2014-01-01 00:05:00 73.11    NA NA
2014-01-01 00:10:00 73.16    NA NA
2014-01-01 00:11:00 73.16 71.11 NA
2014-01-01 00:15:00 73.22 71.11 NA
2014-01-01 00:16:00 73.22 70.12 NA
2014-01-01 00:21:00 73.22 70.16 NA
2014-01-01 00:23:00 73.22 70.16  0
2014-01-01 00:26:00 73.22 70.19  0
2014-01-01 00:28:00 73.22 70.19  1
2014-01-01 00:31:00 73.22 69.16  1
2014-01-01 00:33:00 73.22 69.16  1
2014-01-01 00:38:00 73.22 69.16  0
2014-01-01 00:43:00 73.22 69.16  0
```

Note that for z1 and z2, the legitimate NAs in the end are gone.

Furthermore, if I want to re-sample the data to have the same regular timestamp, both NAs at the beginning and in the end are gone too.

```
> z.timesteps
                       z1    z2 z3
2014-01-01 00:00:00 73.06 71.11  0
2014-01-01 00:05:00 73.11 71.11  0
2014-01-01 00:10:00 73.16 71.11  0
2014-01-01 00:15:00 73.22 71.11  0
2014-01-01 00:20:00 73.22 70.12  0
2014-01-01 00:25:00 73.22 70.16  0
2014-01-01 00:30:00 73.22 70.19  1
2014-01-01 00:35:00 73.22 69.16  1
2014-01-01 00:40:00 73.22 69.16  0
2014-01-01 00:45:00 73.22 69.16  0
2014-01-01 00:50:00 73.22 69.16  0
2014-01-01 00:55:00 73.22 69.16  0
2014-01-01 01:00:00 73.22 69.16  0
```

Is there a way we can achieve what I need? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`na.fill` can help here.  The following line of code will preserve runs of NAs at the beginning and at the end but fill in the remaining NAs using `na.locf`:

```
zz <- na.locf(z, na.rm = FALSE) + 0 * na.fill(z, fill = c(NA, 0, NA))
```

giving:

```
> zz
                       z1    z2 z3
2014-01-01 00:00:00 73.06    NA NA
2014-01-01 00:05:00 73.11    NA NA
2014-01-01 00:10:00 73.16    NA NA
2014-01-01 00:11:00 73.16 71.11 NA
2014-01-01 00:15:00 73.22 71.11 NA
2014-01-01 00:16:00    NA 70.12 NA
2014-01-01 00:21:00    NA 70.16 NA
2014-01-01 00:23:00    NA 70.16  0
2014-01-01 00:26:00    NA 70.19  0
2014-01-01 00:28:00    NA 70.19  1
2014-01-01 00:31:00    NA 69.16  1
2014-01-01 00:33:00    NA    NA  1
2014-01-01 00:38:00    NA    NA  0
2014-01-01 00:43:00    NA    NA  0
```

**Note 1:** We could reduce the `read.table` / `zoo` lines to three lines of the form:

```
z1 <- read.zoo(text = lines1, header = TRUE, sep = ",", tz = "")
```

**Note 2:** Perhaps what you want to do next is:

```
timesteps <- seq(start(zz), start(zz) + 3600, by = "5 min")
m <- merge(zz, zoo(, timesteps))
m.na <- na.locf(m, na.rm = FALSE) + 0 * na.fill(m, fill = c(NA, 0, NA))
window(m.na, timesteps)
```

Comment: The final result that I expect should be the re-sampled zoo object with timesteps as the index. I tried to put `xout=timesteps` in `na.locf` and `na.fill`, but it does not work.

Comment: I have added a `Note 2` in case that is what you are looking for.